# How to pass multiple values from a panda df to pyspark SQL using IN OPERATOR

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The output of my df returns three distinct values as below

```
print(df["ID"])
```

returns three ID's `1`,`2` and `3`.

I want to pass these values within a pyspark SQL

```
 Query = 'select col 1 from temptable where ID IN (*need to pass the ID's here*)
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: if query is a string then convert `df["ID"]` to string. ie. `','.join( df['ID'].astype(str).to_list() )` gives string `"1,2,3"`

Answer (score 1):

If `Query` is a string then convert `df["ID"]` to string

For example

```
','.join( df['ID'].astype(str).to_list() )
```

gives string

```
'1,2,3'
```

And then you can use it in string with query using ie. f-string.

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3]})

text = ','.join( df['ID'].astype(str).to_list() )

Query = f'SELECT col 1 FROM temptable WHERE ID IN ({text})'

print(Query)
```

Result:

```
'SELECT col 1 FROM temptable WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)'
```

---

**EDIT:**

This also works for me

```
text = ','.join( df['ID'].astype(str) )
```

or

```
text = df['ID'].astype(str).str.cat(sep=',')
```

or

```
item = df[ ['ID'] ].astype(str).agg(','.join)  #, axis=0)
text = item['ID']
```

or

```
item = df[ ['ID'] ].astype(str).apply(lambda column: ','.join(column))  #, axis=0)
text = item['ID']
```